# Django deploying on lighttpd automatization

Tags: django, deployment, lighttpd

I have few simple django-based sites and I their number increasing all the time. Every time I deploy the site I need to:

1. Manually create bash-script that start Django FastCGI server.
2. Adding it to etc/init.d to run after server reboot.
3. Creating separate config for Lighttpd to work with FastCGI server and serving static files.

I know how to do it, but I'd like to automate this task if possible.

My dream setup process could look like this:

1. I have a folder somewhere in my /var/ directory. For example: /var/django/
2. I clone one of my projects to the subdirectory of this directory.
3. After that happening one of the following: Some software automatically detects folder creation, and creates all necessary configs and then restart Lighttpd. OR I manually run some kind of script in my new folder to do it.

I tried to look for existing tools for such automation or something similar in the internet, but couldn't find one.

So I'd like to ask is there tools like this out there? Maybe not exactly to install Django apps, but to this kind of process automation in general. Or everybody just writes their own bash script to do such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you had a look at [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.1/index.html) and [puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/)?

Comment: I looked at fabric, but I have impression that it's more about updating and maintaing code, not about initial deployment: While it easy to update/run/install code with it, automatically creating new config based on existing templates, and on the project location is a lot less trivial. But maybe this impression is wrong, I look at it once more. And at puppet too, didn't see this one before.

Comment: Fabric link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I think [fabric](http://fabfile.org) will do the job. I've just started reading through the docs, seems very simple to get started on. Also it has nice Python-ic way of doing things locally and on remote servers.

Comment: Answered about fabric in the previous question, but still thanks!